# Pure CSS Parallax - Firefox translateZ issue? Only half of content is visible on load

Tags: html, css, parallax

I am fiddling around with making a parallax website, have been following the steps from [Keith Clark](https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/) to slowly get to know parallax. However, I stumble upon an issue that looks like a Firefox issue? On load, the first layer and the darkseagreen background layer are cut in half. If I change the translateZ property from -1px to 0, everything is loaded correctly but then the parallax effect isn't working anymore.
If I scroll down or adjust the size of my browser, the rest is visible, but I would like to have it visible on the initial load.

[Link to codepen](https://codepen.io/Criena/pen/dyMvgra) I'm using Firefox 80.0.

```
.parallax {
    perspective: 1px;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
  }

  .parallax__layer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 100vh 0;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .parallax__layer--base {
    transform: translateZ(0);
  }

  .parallax__layer--back {
    transform: translateZ(-1px);
    background-color: darkseagreen;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .title {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was an inherited 'overflow: hidden' that clipped the content in FireFox unnecessarily.

Reading through the original docs I found:

> One important rule to keep in mind when grouping elements is, we
> cannot clip the content of a group. Setting overflow: hidden on a
> parallax__group will break the parallax effect. Unclipped content will
> result in descendant elements overflowing, so we need to be creative
> with the z-index values of the groups to ensure content is correctly
> revealed/hidden as the visitor scrolls through the document.

With this you have to deal with the z-index cleverly, which is kind of an issue in my approach, but I can handle it.

In particular by using intersection observers. Once a certain intersection is reached the z-index is flipped. This makes the entire code more complex, which is what I'm afraid of, but it seems to work.